# How to save a email to a PDF format?

Tags: vb.net, pdf, save, outlook-2010

I want to save all my emails into a PDF format. The file must contains which look similar to the Outlook Reading Pane into Outlook 2010.

Is there a programming way to to this (cause hundreds of emails) ?

Comment: Are you trying to save the body of the email to a pdf ? Could you expand more on what it is your end result would look like.

Comment: Yes, i want to have a PDF file, which contains something similar to the Outlook's Reading Pane.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [openpop](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hpop/) to retrieve all your emails. Then you could loop through each email and save the body to a pdf.